Are certain kinds of gods more likely than others? Is this question meaningful?
Is it meaningful to talk about the likelihood of different kinds of gods, and in what sense a particular kind of god is more likely than another?
For example, one can imagine different kinds of “gods” that are dissimilar to the traditional interpretation of god. For example, one can imagine an evil god, a weird god, a god who has a special desire to create chocolate, etc. What reason do we have to prefer the traditional conception of god over others?

See Ancient Greek Mythology.

@Syed this may be of interest: https://youtu.be/O_sElrgwRFg

Traditional conceptions of God or gods (there are lots of traditions) are defended on the basis of:

personal or reported metaphysical considerations of nature including the nature of self, implying the particularities of perpetual or ubiquitous miracles - which you've ruled out with your intrinsically arbitrary a priori commitment to mechanistic naturalistic monism. (Not that commitments to interventional supernaturalistic dualism are any less arbitrary.)

direct or reported observations of the particularities of conventional miracles, which you've ruled out with your circular assertion of the impossibility of miracles. Conventional miracles are exceptions to the laws of nature, the laws of nature are supported by exceptionless testimony, which testimony we know to be exceptionless because we have excluded testimony of miracles.... (Not that anything else escapes circularity or arbitrary assertion in the end.)

direct or reported revelation, which you've ruled out with your circular assertion of the unreliability of revelation. All purported communication with God can be explained by mental illness or wishful thinking, these explanations are supported by exceptionless testimony, which testimony we know to be exceptionless because we have excluded testimony of purported communication with God.... (Not that anything else escapes circularity or arbitrary assertion in the end.)


Traditional god-concepts are the god-concepts that comport with these considerations, as conveyed to modern individuals either by the traditions which they trust or by the arguments of defenders of those traditions, in the case of converts.
To evaluate the likelihood of god-concepts you first have to try on a set of metaphysical presuppositions - that is, the a priori plausibility of supernatural interventions - that makes god-concepts reasonable in the first place, and then evaluate history and nature. If you start with the opposite presupposition, you can't evaluate the likelihood of god-concepts because you've ruled out everything that could possibly count as evidence.
